Problems with LocalStorage on iOS ProgressiveWebApp
I am completely new to development - another dev coded something for me and now I try to add more functionalities -> and yes, I am using ChatGPT, sorry to the real devs here
The component the dev coded for me is a PushNotifications Component using OneSignal SDK for the OSSN (Open Source SocialNetwork) system - sadly he is not reachable anymore
The component uses a "bell" icon to activate and deactivate push notifications -> that works fine
I added a settings page to user profile now, for better usage
The problem is, that the localstorage on iOS gets not updated correctly - for Android and PC it seems to work, but on iOS the LocalStorage is set to "false" and after reload the page, it's on "true" again
I wanted to change the code to use cookies instead, but the LocalStorage stuff is not from the component, it comes from OneSignalSDKWorker.js (retrieved from their servers), so cookies are not an option I think
this is the Code I am using:
<?php
$user = ossn_loggedin_user();
?>

<div>
    <h3><?php echo ossn_print('onesignal:notifications:settings:title'); ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo ossn_print('onesignal:notifications:settings:description'); ?></p>

    <form id="notification-settings-form" class="notification-settings-form" action="<?php echo ossn_site_url('action/OneSignalNotifications/settings'); ?>" method="post">
        <?php
        $ossn_ts = time();
        $ossn_token = ossn_generate_action_token($ossn_ts);
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="ossn_ts" value="<?php echo $ossn_ts; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ossn_token" value="<?php echo $ossn_token; ?>" />

        <label><?php echo ossn_print('onesignal:notifications:settings:label'); ?></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="notification_status" id="notification_status" value="disable">
        <input type="checkbox" id="notification_toggle" name="notification_status" value="enable">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo ossn_print('save'); ?></button>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Abrufen des aktuellen Status aus dem Local Storage
        var isEnabled = localStorage.getItem('isPushNotificationsEnabled');
        if (isEnabled === 'true') {
            document.getElementById('notification_toggle').checked = true;
            document.getElementById('notification_status').value = 'enable';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('notification_toggle').checked = false;
            document.getElementById('notification_status').value = 'disable';
        }

        // Aktualisieren des Hidden-Input-Werts basierend auf dem Status des Checkbox
        document.getElementById('notification_toggle').addEventListener('change', function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                document.getElementById('notification_status').value = 'enable';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('notification_status').value = 'disable';
            }
        });
    });
    
    document.getElementById('notification-settings-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        // Verhindere das automatische Absenden, um zuerst den Local Storage zu aktualisieren
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = this;
        var status = document.getElementById('notification_status').value;

        if (status === 'enable') {
            localStorage.setItem('isPushNotificationsEnabled', 'true');
            OneSignal.push(function() {
                OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
            });
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('isPushNotificationsEnabled', 'false');
            OneSignal.push(function() {
                OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
            });
        }

        // Sende das Formular nach dem Aktualisieren des Local Storage ab
        form.submit();
    });

</script>

If someone want to inspect the whole component, I uploaded it here:
text
I tried nothing so far, because I only use ChatGPT and it's not helpful with this
